# Rails - Possible to convert a PDF to Images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick

I have a Rails 3 app with PaperClip/S3...

Is it possible to allow a user to upload a PDF, convert the PDF to images, and then upload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Take a look at imagemagick and rmagick plugin for ruby.  This allows you to do all kinds of image conversions, including PDF to jpeg.

http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

EDIT:

untested sample code:

```
require 'RMagick'
pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("doc.pdf")
pdf.write("myimage.jpg")
```

if doc.pdf has 3 pages, this should output 3 images:
myimage.jpg.0
myimage.jpg.1
myimage.jpg.2

take a look at the end of the documentation on this page, which shows a similar example with a multi-frame gif converted to multiple PNGs using imagelist:
http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#write

Comment: thanks, but I was hoping for more of a tutorial or sample project.. Problem is I want to upload a PDF with multiple pages and convert that to multiple images.

Comment: rmagick can do do that.  You can create an ImageList from a pdf, and write the pages individually to images.  I posted some code (untested, but should be close) in my updated answer.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the output in only one large image, instead of one image for each page of the pdf file?

Comment: If I'm using Carrierwave - how do I get the image in place of "doc.pdf" ?