# Ruby on Rails JPEG to PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, amazon-s3, jpeg

I want to have a `JPEG` upload feature on my website and have those images converted to `PDF` and then saved to my `S3`.

I know how to upload stuff to `S3` so that's not the problem. The problem here is the conversion from a couple of uploaded images to `PDF`. What am I looking at?

I searched a lot but found no gems that specifically does what I want. Found some online services but they didn't provide `API`s. Found `prawn` and other gems that deal with `PDF` but the source wasn't some pictures.

How can I possibly achieve this in some feasible way?

P.S. I will be using heroku to host my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you install ImageMagick and the 'rmagick' gem the following snippet works to convert most images to PDF files (opposite situation: [Rails - Possible to convert a PDF to Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110730/rails-possible-to-convert-a-pdf-to-images))

```
require 'rmagick'
jpg = Magick::ImageList.new("myimage.jpg")
jpg.write("doc.pdf")
```

Comment: That is sweet. I will give it a shot and let you know What I have accomplished Thanks a lot.

Comment: I couldn't get ImageMagick on my Windows computer, but I did test it on Linux. Don't forget to mark my answer :D

Comment: Works like a charm <3

Comment: Works! Additional you must change the policy.xml to read and write of type PDF

Comment: One thing worth being aware of is that to deploy this on Heroku you'll probably need to use the following buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt as you can't "brew install" imagemagick on Linux