# ActionView::Template::Error (ActiveStorage::InvariableError) in image_tag for PDF file

Tags: rails-activestorage

I am trying to show application/pdf file preview by variant. I installed mutool 1.17 and specified its path in `config/environments/development.rb`.

```
config.active_storage.paths[:mutool] = '/usr/local/bin/mutool'
```

View is

```
<%= image_tag post.pdf.variant(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>
```

What should I do else to show PDF file preview?

Image files (jpeg and png) are shown without any issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4111637/4453714 Take a look at pdf to image converting sample, it can be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I found it was my mistake. I oversaw the description in Active Storage document. I should use preview for PDF. That's it.

- `<%= image_tag post.pdf.variant(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>`

+ `<%= image_tag post.pdf.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>`